# $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}{8x(x+1)-\sqrt{4x^2+2x}\cdot\sqrt[3]{64x^3+144x^2+90x+17}}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}{8x(x+1)-\sqrt{4x^2+2x}\cdot\sqrt[3]{64x^3+144x^2+90x+17}}$$

I know that it's $\infty - \infty$, but the square root and cube root make it too complicated. Can anyone help me to deal with this problem? Thank you

Comment: Write $\sqrt{4x^2+2x}$ as $2x(1+1/(2x))^{1/2}$ and $\sqrt[3]{64x^3+144x^2+90x+17}$ as $4x(1+9/(4x)+45/(32x^2)+17/(64x^3))$

Comment: Hint: if $a\approx b$, $a-b\approx\frac{a^6-b^6}{6a^5}$. For $a:=8x(x+1),\,b:=\sqrt{4x^2+2x}\sqrt[3]{64x^3+144x^2+90x+17}$, you need only compute $a^6-b^6$ down to degrees as low as the $x^{10}$ term.

Comment: @J.G. hmmm, I still cant prove $a-b\approx\frac{a^6-b^6}{6a^5}$

Comment: @ZAhmed I've tried it but it's still bring me to $0.0$

Comment: The exact denominator is $a^5+a^4b+\cdots+b^5$, with six similar terms.

Comment: @J.G. Oh, right, I understand, but is there another way to deal with this problem? Cause I dont want to go to $x^10$ term :<

Comment: Why not? The $x^{12}$ coefficient's easy, and the $x^{11}$ and $x^{10}$ terms only have slightly more combinatorial complexity when you figure out their coefficients. It's the middle degrees, not the high or low ones, that would be the hardest to work out.

Comment: Use the substitution $x=1/t$ and the expression can be written as $(8/t^2)\left(1+t-\sqrt{1+(t/2)}\sqrt[3]{1+9t/4+\dots}\right)$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

First, notice that
$$64x^3+144x^2+90x+17=(2 x+1) \left(32 x^2+56 x+17\right)$$

One of my professors used to tell us *"We are almost closer to $0$ than to $\infty$"*. So, start making $x=\frac 1 y$ and simplify to make the expression
$$\frac{8 (1+y)-\sqrt{2} (2+y)^{5/6} \sqrt[3]{ 32+56y+17 y^2}}{y^2}$$ So, for the limit, we just need to expand the numerator to $O(y^3)$ which is not much work using the binomial expansion.

Comment: Very good but some more good work remains

Comment: @ZAhmed. It took me 2 minutes with pen and paper

Comment: @ZAhmed. Three not four